# So Time Mah Betas Userscript, displays the length of Area 51 public betas

Tags: script, area51

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screen Capture of "public beta duration" text]

### About

This script was created to address [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/122095/can-we-display-how-long-launched-sites-were-in-beta-on-their-area-51-proposals): When viewing the Area 51 proposal for any site, this script adds a "public beta duration" block showing the length of the public beta.

#### License

[The Unicorn Software License](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn/)

#### Download

[Install version 1.1.0](http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/SoTimeMahBetas.user.js)

#### Platform

Google Chrome / Greasemonkey / any other browser supporting Userscripts.

### Contact

This was created by [Josh's Socks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151695/joshs-socks), he can be contacted at `socks -at- josh -dot- gitlin -dot- name`, or [via my website](http://josh.gitlin.name/contact).

### Code

Written in JavaScript, uses jQuery and Stack Exchange API v2.0 (to get the launch date of a site)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'll never **need** this but it uses jQuery so it must be awesome. Good Job!

Comment: Haha, thanks Jacob. It's useful if you want to compare how long each site was in beta, for example to plan how long it will be until existing beta sites launch.